# Google Spreadsheet: Set a default value to all the cells in a column with/with out script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to set a default value to a cell in a spreadsheet?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you´re after. Can you try to clarify what you want to do?

If you go to Tools/Script editor and enter the following code, the cells A2 through A11 will be set to 42 when any cell is edited:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, 10).setValue(42);
}
```